# how to implement sigma in haskell?

Tags: algorithm, haskell

i'm learning haskell and i'm trying to solve http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=1098

i solved this problem using other language so i know the solution

```
answerTo(n, d) = func(n, d) - func(n, d - 1)

func(n, d) = Σ(func(k - 2, d -1) * func(n - k, d)) | 2 <= k <= n, k is even
func(0, d) = 1
```

and i need to implement func in haskell. i don't know how to.

```
func n d
    | n < 0 || d < 0 = 0
    | n == 0 && d >= 0 = 1
    | otherwise = --need to implement Σ(func (k - 2) (d -1)) * (func (n - k) d) | 2 <= k <= n, k is even
```

i solved in this way

```
func (n, d)
    | n == 0 && d >= 0 = 1
    | n < 0 || d < 0 = 0
    | otherwise = sum (zipWith (*) (map func arg1) (map func arg2))
    where
        arg1 = [(k - 2, d - 1) | k <- filter even [2..n]]
        arg2 = [(n - k, d) | k <- filter even [2..n]]
```

there are other solutions more graceful?

Comment: What is sigma, aside from the Greek letter &sigma;? What is this "other language"?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma_function) tells me there are 3 sigma functions... Which one are you seeking?

Comment: sigma means Σ. i edited

Comment: @user3703559, the capital letter sigma also has a lot of meanings. Do you mean the *sum*?

Comment: yes. it just means sum

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for a code review - try codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

The [Math.NumberTheory.Primes.Factorization](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi-0.4.1.0/docs/Math-NumberTheory-Primes-Factorisation.html) module in the [arithmoi](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi-0.4.1.0) package includes a σ function that may be the one you need, along with other related functions. You can click through to the source code for that function if you like.

#### Edit

Now that you've clarified what you mean, the answer is simple. You need to enumerate the values you need and then sum them. The easiest way to do this is using the `sum` function to sum a list that you create using a list comprehension:

```
func n d
    | n < 0 || d < 0 = 0
    | n == 0 && d >= 0 = 1
    | otherwise = sum [func (k - 2) (d - 1) * func (n - k) d | k <- [2,4..n]]
```

Comment: thank you very much. i think functional languages are very awesome

Comment: Note that this code is very inefficient. I haven't analyzed it in detail, but it seems quite likely that you end up repeating a lot of calculations. If that is so, you may want to consider using dynamic programming (perhaps using lazy vectors) or finding a better algorithm. Less importantly, you test each time for too many base cases. You'd probably be better off avoiding that—it's easy to cut out at least one of those comparisons most of the time.